# legally innocent and not guilty

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, difference

I'd like to know if there's any difference between "legally innocent" and "not guilty."

> The scientist is legally innocent.

> The scientist is not guilty.

Comment: context please.

Comment: If the scientist has gone on trial, which can be used?

Comment: Laws are different from place to place. Where exactly? Some jurisdictions have a concept of "innocent" on top of "not guilty". Where I live, legally, there's only "not guilty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to describe the result of trial is "guilty" or "not guilty".  These are the terms that juries use to give verdicts.  The jury is asked "How do you find the defendant" and the fore-person replies either "guilty" or "not guilty".  Never "Innocent".

A person is legally innocent until they have been found guilty in court.
"Legally innocent" sounds like weasel words: it might be used to imply that the person is ethically or morally culpable, but is innocent in the view of the law, owing to the fact that they haven't (yet) been found guilty in a court.